# 2 git repositories in one directory

Tags: git, joomla, github

As example there is joomla-cms repo. It has structure like this

```
root
   administrator
   components
   media
   library
```

Now I come in and what to create extension for joomla at the same time having latest Joomla version from repo. and structure is like this.

```
root
   administrator
   components
```

It only adds new folders inside joomla repo but in many different folders. Even more my extension has half files public for free version and half private repo for paid version. It is a different repos. And I want all this be in one Joomla installation on my PC.

So how I set up that I can update all repos?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution suits you:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

It allows you to have a project repository and inside have sub-repositories that are independent repositories themselves, but which the project repository is connected to.

Comment: This is I am aware about. But the problem is that one Joolma extension is in different folders. With this submodules I'll have to create repo for every folder. It will be one extension in 2 repos. Not very well :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create a sperate git repository for your Joomla! extension like this [joomla-extensions/boilerplate: Boilerplate files for Joomla! extensions](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/boilerplate) if you want to version control your own extension.

Then manually install or update your extension via administration page.